# Overlay Causing Button to Become Unclickable

Tags: html, css

I'm running into the issue where, after applying a color overlay on an image, the content, like the button, is no longer clickable. I've narrowed down the issue to the *.overlay:before* CSS code. When I comment out this section of code, I can click on the button again. However, I can't figure out what the exact cause is within the code. Any help would be much appreciated!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/suomyone/3ewzur9b/1/

Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="overlay blue2" id="contact" name="contact">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <p><b>T:</b> ###-###-####</p>
    <p><b>F:</b> ###-###-####</p>
    <button type="button" class="contactButton">Contact Us</button>
</section>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.blue2 {
    background-color: rgba(36, 131, 178, 0.9);
}

#contact {
    color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 1.875em 2.8125em 0 2.815em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#contact img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.contactButton {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.864375em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 10.55676em;
    height: 1.80766em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #F7CB5F;
    border: 1px solid #F7CB5F;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contactButton:hover {
    background-color: #2483B2;
    border: 1px solid #2483B2;
}

.contactButton:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the button a position other then the default (static) and it responds:

```
.contactButton {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.864375em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 10.55676em;
  height: 1.80766em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #F7CB5F;
  border: 1px solid #F7CB5F;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative; /* NEW */
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3ewzur9b/2/)**

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Mind I ask what the logic is behind the solution? How did setting its position to relative solve the issue?

Comment: Giving the button the relative position establishes a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again!